# Include external font ttf in android project in Xamarin C#

Tags: xamarin

I am developing an android app with Xamarin Studio in C# .NET. I have to use an external font (TTF) file in app. I have copied this ttf file into Assets folder. Now, how to use it in app by axml or code?

It is a Xamarin.Android application.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
var typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (context.Assets, fileName);
```

Where `filename` would be the name of your font, for example `Roboto-Light.ttf` and `context` is, well, your `Context`.